# Distortion on recording without clipping

Tags: distortion

I record podcast interviews on my iPhone using a Rode [`mobile interview kit`](https://www.rode.com/microphones/sc6-lik). My recordings were very clear until I switched recording apps, but now I'm getting distortion at moderate volume -- nowhere close to clipping.

All the advice I've seen about fixing distortion relates to distortion from clipping, but that's not my problem. Here's a clip containing the distortion -- http://rickmohr.net/Downloads/distortion.wav

Any suggestions for repairing the audio? I'm using Audacity.

Comment: For starters, stop using audacity. If you are on a budget, use something like reaper.

Comment: Well I’d say the obvious simple solution is to switch back to the old recording app.

Comment: Yes I will switch recording apps. Yes I'm open to ditching Audacity. Still looking for ideas on repairing the existing distortion -- maybe it's not really possible with any software.